# React native issue - IOS version of app works fine in all scenario but crashes the Android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am having issues in my react native app where certain feature is crashing the app on android device, but it is working just fine on IOS devices. There is a reshare feature in my app which crashes android devices. Also when I navigate to some pages the android devices crash, but IOS version just works fine.

Can somebody provide me a reason on why it might be happening.

Here are the stack trace errors

[image: stack trace]

Here is the peace of code

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import IMProfileSettings from '../components/IMProfileSettings/IMProfileSettings';
import { logout } from '../../../onboarding/redux/auth';
import { IMLocalized } from '../../../localization/IMLocalization';
import { Appearance } from 'react-native-appearance';
import AppStyles from '../../../../AppStyles';
import SocialNetworkConfig from '../../../../SocialNetworkConfig';

class IMProfileSettingsScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.appStyles = props.route.params?.appStyles || AppStyles;
    let COLOR_SCHEME = Appearance.getColorScheme();
    let currentTheme = this.appStyles.navThemeConstants[COLOR_SCHEME];
    this.props.navigation.setOptions({
      headerTitle: IMLocalized('Profile Settings'),
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: currentTheme.backgroundColor,
        borderBottomColor: currentTheme.hairlineColor,
      },
      headerTintColor: currentTheme.fontColor,
    });
    this.didFocusSubscription = props.navigation.addListener(
      'focus',
      (payload) =>
        BackHandler.addEventListener(
          'hardwareBackPress',
          this.onBackButtonPressAndroid,
        ),
    );
    this.lastScreenTitle = this.props.route.params.lastScreenTitle;
    this.appConfig = this.props.route.params?.appConfig || SocialNetworkConfig;
    if (!this.lastScreenTitle) {
      this.lastScreenTitle = 'Profile';
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.willBlurSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'beforeRemove',
      (payload) =>
        BackHandler.removeEventListener(
          'hardwareBackPress',
          this.onBackButtonPressAndroid,
        ),
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.didFocusSubscription && this.didFocusSubscription();
    this.willBlurSubscription && this.willBlurSubscription();
  }

  onBackButtonPressAndroid = () => {
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
    return true;
  };

  onLogout = () => {
    this.props.logout();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <IMProfileSettings
        navigation={this.props.navigation}
        onLogout={this.props.logout}
        lastScreenTitle={this.lastScreenTitle}
        user={this.props.user}
        appStyles={this.appStyles}
        appConfig={this.appConfig}
      />
    );
  }
}

IMProfileSettingsScreen.propTypes = {};

const mapStateToProps = ({ auth }) => {
  return {
    user: auth.user,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  logout,
})(IMProfileSettingsScreen);
```

Comment: Hi @suryansh soni, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you have a crash log/stack trace that you could share? If not, it's gonna be quite hard to give you a helping hand. :-)

Comment: Adding to what @karllindmark said (which you should do first), some of the things that crashed my android apps previously and worked on ios are: Google maps (you will need to add the maps api or the app crashes), sharing works differently on the platforms, and other libraries or modules that have different support for the platforms for which you need to follow the documentation before installing.

Comment: I have updated the question